# swing application , spring application context error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, swing

where is the error in this applicationContext.fml file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" abstract="true">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mostra"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="*****"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>./resources/employee.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
<property name="sessionFactory">
<ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

i get "referenced bean dataSource" is invalid (abstract or no bean class and no factory bean)....just WHY ?????

i use a similar code in un other app and all works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you have `abstract="true"` in your datasource definition

Comment: Exact same error? could be that your old file is accessible somewhere in the classpath still - try a clean/refresh if you have eclipse

Comment: i moved the project to MyEclipse and the error is gone, thanks anyway